# Fastest way to convert large text file (10GB) containing lists of nested dictonaries to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, text

I have large text files containing lists of nested dictionaries of the below sample format:

```
[ {key1:value1, key2:value2, key3: { key3_key1:key3_value1,
        key3_key2:key3_value2
      } ]
```

Trying to convert each list as pandas data frame row of the following column format

`columns = [key1, key2, key3_key1, key3_key2]`

What is the fastest way to achieve a complete data frame?

Comment: Is it a valid json file?

Comment: To do it you need either ```.apply``` or ```lambda```,
 here is a post that may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388201/fastest-way-to-create-a-pandas-column-conditionally

Comment: @micric, its not a valid json file. Its a text file containing lists of nested dictionaries. json.loads doesnt work on it.

Comment: Thanks @Mark, I can read the text file line after line and append rows to a dataframe. Isn't that too slow?  Should I be taking chunks to different cores and then apply the row append function?

Comment: I would suggest reading it into a python array of arrays, and then bulk sending that to Pandas. It's faster than appending rows to a dataframe one at a time.