# Apply function to DataFrame and create new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Player': ['Pele', 'Platini', 'Beckenbauer'],
                    'Position': ['Forward', 'Midfielder', 'Defender']})
```

And I have this function I need to apply to the dataframe, creating a new column 'color'.

```
def color(position):
    if position == 'Forward':
        color = 'black'
    elif position == 'Midfielder':
        color = 'white'
    elif position == 'Defender':
        color = 'red'

    return color
```

I have tried:

```
df['Color'] = df.apply(color, axis=1)
```

But I get the error:

```
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0')
```

---

How do I do this?

Comment: you are passing all the column values. So you need to specifywhich column value you are referring to.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388201/fastest-way-to-create-a-pandas-column-conditionally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) here. Create a mapping dictionary and feed it to `pd.Series.map`

```
mapping = {'Forward':'black', 'Midfielder':'white', 'Defender':'red'}
df['Color'] = df['Position'].map(mapping)

        Player    Position  Color
0         Pele     Forward  black
1      Platini  Midfielder  white
2  Beckenbauer    Defender    red
```

Comment: I like this. Less code.

Comment: @8-BitBorges `.map` comes in handy for mapping problems ;) Glad this helped you

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
df['color'] = df['Position'].apply(color)
```

**Or**

```
def color(position):
    pos = position['Position']
    if pos == 'Forward':
        color = 'black'
    elif pos == 'Midfielder':
        color = 'white'
    elif pos == 'Defender':
        color = 'red'

    return color

df['color'] = df.apply(color, axis=1)
```

---

```
    Player      Position    color
0   Pele        Forward     black
1   Platini     Midfielder  white
2   Beckenbauer Defender    red
```